Broke my mac network after apache/ssl changes
I tried to configure Apache2 with SSL for local web development on my Mac (MacOS Ventura).
What I did with apache/ssl was : install httpd and make some basic configuration. Enable mod_ssl module, generate .crt and .key, add the virtual host to httpd.conf (:443 for SSL).
I don't know when but at some point I must have done something wrong because suddenly I wasn't able to go on the web at all : issue seems to be that my connection are not secured anymore. (ERR_INVALID_HANDLE on Chrome on whatever website)
I tried to change the wifi connection, same. Also same on all browser (chrome, firefox, safari). Works on my other mac which is connected to the same network. Also clean the cache. Tried to reboot the computer several times.
Now, I removed the .crt and .key from /private/etc/apache2 file.
I restaured the original configuration files (copy from original apache directory).
Tried to restore network parameters by removing in /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration :
    com.apple.airport.preferences.plist
    com.apple.network.eapolclient.configuration.plist
    com.apple.wifi.message-tracer.plist
    NetworkInterfaces.plist
    preferences.plist

If I launch sudo apachectl restart :
    (48)Adress already in use: AH00072: made_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
    (48)Adress already in use: AH00072: made_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
    no listening sockets available, shutting down
    AH00015: Unable to open logs

If I ping 8.8.8.8, connection is immediately closed :
    ping google.com
    PING google.com (216.58.213.78): 56 data bytes  # ping stops after that

Nothing works, I don't know what to do anymore and I'm not even sure to understand what is going on. Any suggestion ?

After you removed all those network settings plists, did you reboot your Mac?

Yes, I also re install the os with restauration system, still nothing. Everything looks like it's working (wifi well connected, no error messages in particular) but even airdrop, iMessage or iCloud drive don't work...
